After upgrade of Ubuntu, dual install with Windows 10 is now only Ubuntu
I had a functioning dual install of Windows 10 and Ubuntu. While working in Ubuntu, I was offered an upgrade of Ubuntu and accepted. The upgrade took a long time. When it finished, I was no longer offered the choice of booting either of the OSs. My laptop booted directly into Ubuntu and I cannot access the Windows partition where my data files and my access to Microsoft OneDrive are located. Please help.

Have you run sudo update-grub ? Does it show Windows? Did Windows also do an update when you shut it down? It can restore setting that prevent grub from seeing the Windows partition. Make sure Windows fast startup, bitlocker and need for chkdsk are all off.

It found Windows 10 on /dev/sda2 and said it was adding a boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings. But on Restart no option to choose Windows appeared. It again booted directly into Ubuntu.

Windows fast startup, bitlocker and need for chkdsk are all off.

Correction: Upon research of "fast startup," I learned that my assumption that each of these was opt-in was incorrect. I have never disabled fast startup and now cannot access Windows 10 to opt-out.

Grub only boots working Windows, that meand fast startup, bitlocker & need for chkdsk must be off. If UEFI you should be able to directly boot from UEFI one time boot menu. If you cannot boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, then you need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to fix Windows. Windows turns fast startup back on with some updates.          https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
